# Hibernate Spatial with MySQL and Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, gis, hibernate-spatial

I am developing an app that will store location data from map to the MySQL database.I came across MySQL spatial data types which can be useful to perform some operations on the location data.
I wanted to integrate hibernate spatial with spring boot but I am unable to do so.I have tried different variations of code but every time this is failing.

I would like to see one complete example for MySQL spatial with following tools :
Spring Boot (latest version with latest hibernate)
MySQL.

also which dependency for hibernate spatial should I use and what to mention in the properties file and how the code should be?

Did found other solutions but those are outdated and not working when implemented.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-spatial. A recently updated tutorial on Hibernate Spatial with MySQL

Comment: Yes, I looked into this but with the latest version I am not able to create Polygon. It always returns me NoSuchMethodException : getExteriorRing()

Comment: Could you post the stack trace?